# Firebase and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, backfire, backbonefire

I am trying to build a basic app using Backbone and Firebase:

http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/6324/

```
var counter = 0;

var Box = Backbone.Firebase.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        number: 0
    },
    //firebase: new Firebase('https://backbone-firebase.firebaseio.com/box')
});

var BoxList = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    model: Box,
    firebase: new Firebase('https://backbone-firebase.firebaseio.com/')
});

var Boxes = new BoxList;

var AddBox = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#addBox'),
    events: {
        "click" : 'addBox'
    },
    addBox: function () {
        console.log("adding box");
        Boxes.add({
            number: counter
        });
        counter = counter+1;
    }
});

var addBox = new AddBox();
```

Error stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function backfire.min.js:1

b.Firebase.Collection.b.Collection.extend.constructor backfire.min.js:1
d backbone-min.js:27
(anonymous function) (index):56
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-git2.js:4397
elemData.handle jquery-git2.js:4076

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of 1 backfire.min.js:1
a.extend._childAdded backfire.min.js:1
(anonymous function) firebase.js:93
ic firebase.js:43
Wd firebase.js:93
Ud.Jb firebase.js:93
Xd.Jb firebase.js:94
(anonymous function) firebase.js:109
(anonymous function) firebase.js:59
cc firebase.js:55
R firebase.js:59
(anonymous function) firebase.js:109
Sa firebase.js:23xe firebase.js:109
W firebase.js:109
h.hc firebase.js:117
h.gc firebase.js:85
dd.gc firebase.js:76
(anonymous function) firebase.js:74
Lc firebase.js:58
W.onmessage firebase.js:57
```

The problem is, I am getting a lot of weird errors with Firebase. I have read that weird bugs exist in Firefox, but now I am using Chrome and getting different errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please include the full error message in your question. There's an "edit" link right under it for that purpose.

Comment: Version information would also be crucial for an obscure bug like this. Please see [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some help with wording questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here.

- BackboneFire (formally BackFire) has been updated to a 0.5 version with a lot of updates. Rather than using the `firebase` property you use the `url` property to specify your Firebase reference.
- Don't use a `Backbone.Firebase.Model` with a `Backbone.Firebase.Collection`. A collection can manage it's models events. In the 0.5 model the models within a `Backbone.Firebase.Collection` have a firebase reference that can handle their updates to Firebase.

**The issue here is that you're trying to sync a primitive value**, a string in this case.

Rather than sync the string go one level up and sync the object. Backbone represents models and not primitives. Therefore everything synced in BackboneFire has to be an object as well.